# Render prop in FlatList using a .json in Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a json file that it is passed in a reducer like so:

```
import data from './LibraryList.json';

export default () => data;
```

this is the index.js for all of my reducers.

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import LibraryReducer from './LibraryReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    libraries: () => LibraryReducer

});
```

and the App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';
import { Header} from './components/common'
import LibraryList from './components/LibraryList';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
            <View>
                <Header headerText="Tech Stack" />
                <LibraryList />
            </View>
        </Provider>
    )
}

export default App;
```

This is how i connect to the reducer and map the state to the props but unfortunately it is not rendering my Text components, it does not even print my console.log("hey").

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ListItem from './ListItem';



class LibraryList extends Component {

    renderItem({library}) {
        console.log("hey");
        return <Text> {library.title}</Text>
    }
    render() {

        return (

            <FlatList
                data={this.props.libraries}
                keyExtractor={library => library.id.toString()}
                renderItem={({item}) => this.renderItem(item)}
            />

        );
    }
}  

const mapStateToProps = state => {

    return { libraries: state.libraries };
} 

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LibraryList);
```

When i console.log the state this is all i get:

```
ƒ _default() {
    return _LibraryList.default;
  }
```

instead of my array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be in your `combineReducers`. The key `libraries` is returning a function - `LibraryReducer` - which is again returning a function.

Try returning the `LibraryReducer` directly instead of using a function that returns it.

```
export default combineReducers({
    libraries: LibraryReducer // no function. LibraryReducer itself is a function
});
```

**EDIT:**

I would also recommend that you try out setting the data as initial state for your reducer. Might be slightly more code, but will be much more scalable if in future you want to add more keys to the `libraries` reducer state.

```
import librariesData from './LibraryList.json';

const initialState = {
  data: librariesData,
}

export default function librariesReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  return state;
}
```

Your selector in the component will change slightly:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  libraries: state.libraries.data,
});
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, i accidentally mistyped the function and didn't notice!!